# Transport to Krabi Airport

Tags: transportation, krabi, kbv

I will be staying in Krabi on 29 October 2017. My flight from Krabi airport is at 8.00 am on 30 October 2017. I have to be at the airport at least by 7.00 am. Please advise me the cheapest and most efficient transport to the airport. (I will be only carrying a backpack).

Comment: I'm fairly sure the airport bus is your best option, but I'm not Ure about the schedule.

Comment: Assuming you are taking the 8 am AirAsia flight to KL, keep in mind check closes one hour before departure, so you need to be there earlier than 7.

Comment: Yes I got to be at airport a hour before the flight.. if i can't find transport by 6.30am. I think the only option is to put a night at airport rite.